# Get median in Excel for true values only

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In my Excel I do some caluclations for `median` and `average`.

Now I want to get `median` for the top 20 `percentile` of the records like (A and B column, total of apx 5000 rows):

```
3310        TRUE
2250        TRUE
2161        FALSE
```

The below formula is beeing used to get the top 20 `percentile`:

```
=A1>=PERCENTILE(A1:A5000;0,8)
```

Now, how do I get `median` fot the records having Column B set as `TRUE`

For Average I could just do `=AVERAGE.IF(B1:B5000;TRUE;A1:A5000)` but not for median.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate function for that, but we can use a nested formula.
Remember it is an array formula so use Ctrl, Shift, and Enter.

Use this for the percentile (not an array formula):

```
=IF(A1>=PERCENTILE($A$1:$A$5000;0,8);"TOP";"NOT")
```

And this for TRUE

```
= MEDIAN(IF(B1:B5000="TOP";A1:A5000))
```

This for FALSE

```
= MEDIAN(IF(B1:B5000="NOT";A1:A5000))
```

And remember Ctrl, Shift, and Enter.

Comment: Works. Thank you. However when switiching `TRUE` => `FALSE` the output is 0. In my case it should be `20`. Any idea what causing this?

Comment: = MEDIAN(IF(B1:B5000=TRUE;A1:A5000;20) Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, like below. Just get median for the remaining 80%, the ones with value set as FALSE
`{= MEDIAN(IF(E2:E50000=FALSE;C2:C50000))}`

Comment: It has something to do with FALSE I'm unsure what exactly. I'd recommend just changing the percentile, check the edit.